# sending a parameter to function in a var?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to save a function in a var in JavaScript and then present it on my webpage.
I am making a calender and I want to make each day which is in a TD tag into a button that when I press invokes a function.

This is what I have tried:

```
padding +="<td class='currentmonth'
onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#00FF00\"' 
onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'
onclick='alert(i)'>"+i+"</td>";
```

As you can see `on-click` I want it to alert `i` which is a JavaScript var but it won't work! It doesn't let me send `i` anywhere.
Please help!

Comment: it is taken as String so it wont work,

Comment: Try: `...onclick='alert(" + i + ")'>...`

Comment: tnx it works perfctely

Comment: Also, use css `:hover` for the background change

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this,

```
padding +="<td class='currentmonth'
onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#00FF00\"' 
onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'
onclick='alert('"+i+"')'>"+i+"</td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use this kind of statement, so you can have multiple commands on the onclick call

```
    padding +="<td class='currentmonth'
onMouseOver='this.style.background=\"#00FF00\"' 
onMouseOut='this.style.background=\"#FFFFFF\"'
onclick='alert(\"" + i + "\");anotherFunctionCalled();'>" + i +"</td>";
```